# exim4 configuration with SMTP: daemon abandoned

Tags: php, debian, exim

I'm trying to configure `exim4` to send emails on `Debian 9`.

I have a `SMTP` server `192.168.202.22`, which listens on port `25`. (tested with telnet)

I'm able to send email with telnet connecting to this `SMTP server`.

I need to send message with `PHP` script, which I found here [w3schools php7 email send](https://www.w3schools.com/php7/func_mail_mail.asp)

I think the problem will be in `exim4` configuration. I tried to configure it according to [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim) tutorial, but it's still not working.

I have this message in paniclog:

```
2019-07-31 14:51:51 socket bind() to port 25 for address 192.168.202.22 failed: Cannot assign requested address: daemon abandoned
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start exim again when it is already running. You must first stop exim, then you can start it again.

Comment: Thank you Michael for reply. Why do you think that I started exim after it's already running?

Comment: @culter Because that's the cause of that error message.

Comment: Ok, I tried to start exim4 again with /etc/init.d/exim4 start, but no new similar message appeared in paniclog. Anyway, it doesn't explain why it's not working or am I wrong? Thanks